# I have an extra white empty line in my xml file generated in laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel

This is my Code which Generate XML File.

```
if ($type == 'xml') {
            $output = View::make('admin.shows.stewards-book-print', compact('ConfData', 'BOBData', 'RestData', 'show', 'type', 'showDates', 'showUniqueDays', 'showDays', 'JuniorsData', 'mixedData'))->render();

        $output = trim($output);
        $stewAbbrevType = 'stewards-book-'.$abbrevType.'.xml';

        //add xml header - blade does not seem to like it
        $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n".$output;

        return response($xml)
            ->header('Content-type', 'application/xml')
            ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename='.$stewAbbrevType);

    }
```

My Output is like this and i have to remove these gap only

```
<AwardClass>FRI:&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;  WB________ &#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;  RWB________ &#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32; POINTS________ &#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32; BITCHES________</AwardClass>
 
<ClassHed>Boston Terriers, Veteran Bitches 7 Yrs. &amp; Older </ClassHed>
<ENTRYOBED1><b>40&#09;</b><b>(*) GCHB CH AVALON'S THE ANGEL DID SAY NP36263201</b>. 2013-12-03. Brdr: Lynda Bradley. GCH CH CHRIMASO'S ARE WE THERE YET? - GCH CH COOL SAPPHIRE SKY AT DAWN FOR AVALON. Owners: <b>Lynda Bradley. </b></ENTRYOBED1>
<ENTRYOBED1><b>42&#09;</b><b>(*) CH COOL CHAMPAGNE KISSES NP35702401</b>. 2013-06-13. Brdr: Melany Anaya. GCH CH KEN'S N' PEJA'S A' HORSE OF COURSE BN RA ACT2 CGCA TKI - GCH CH COOL CHERISHED MOMENTS BY AVALON. Owners: <b>Melany Anaya. </b></ENTRYOBED1>
 
<ClassHed>Boston Terriers, Best of Breed Competition </ClassHed>
<ENTRYOBED1><b>37&#09;</b><b>(*) CH DJB'S HOORAY FOR HOLLYWOOD NP57451901</b>. 2019-10-24. Brdr: Jeanne Bertsch/Dennis Bertsch. GCHB CH MAXIMUM AND MTNVIEWS CAUSIN CONFUSION - GCH CH TOUCH OF MAGIC BIT O HONEY AT DJB. Owners: <b>Jeanne Bertsch/Dennis Bertsch/Theresa Janzen/Catherine Jones. </b>(Dog)</ENTRYOBED1>
```

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: The gaps are line feed characters that you output in the view render. *btw* Your example XML is missing the document element.